# MVC State - Object is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, state-management

I'm sure this has a simple answer. Forgive my ignorance; after 15 years of ASPNET WebForms this newfangled web v2.0 stuff is kicking my rear.

I'm trying to understand why my `WebUser` object is null on HttpPost.

So I have this controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult PrivateKey()
{
  var pk = new PrivateKey { WebUser = GetWebUserFromSession() };
  return View(pk);
}
```

This works fine and my razor view can access the members of `PrivateKey.WebUser` without issue.

The problem arises on the HttpPost action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PrivateKey(PrivateKey pkey)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pkey.Value))
    return View(pkey);

  // pkey.WebUser is always null :(
  // TestKeyAgainstMockCipher(pkey.Value, pkey.WebUser);

  InsertSecuredMasterKeyIntoSession(pkey.Value);
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

So for a reason that I'm sure is totally legitimate, my `PrivateKey` object comes through the HttpPost okay but the referenced `WebUser` property contained within the `PrivateKey` object is always null.

I'm not sure if MVC requires a `[Serializable]` attribute be placed on the `WebUser` property or if I'm using the HttpPost incorrectly or even if its just accepted practice in MVC to continually run back to the I/O datastore to constantly fetch data rather than maintaining a standard object oriented data structure in memory to be passed around.

If it would help, here's the view I'm trying to get working:

```
@model KeePassWeb.Domain.Models.PrivateKey

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "PrivateKey";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterPage.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div class="privatekey">
    <table style="">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:128px; height: 75px;"></td>
            <td style="width:291px; height: 75px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:128px; height: 25px;"></td>
            <td style="width:291px; height: 25px; ">
                @Html.PasswordFor(x =>x.Value, new { @class = "form-control", id="txtMasterPass", style = "width:65%", placeHolder = "Password" })
            <input Id="btnMasterPass" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="../Images/big_info.png" height="32px" width="32px" style="margin-right:8px;" alt="info" /></td>
        <td>
            @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.WebUser.Padding)) {
                @:This is your first login. Please create a private key passphrase.
            }
            else {
                @:Please enter your private key to access your wallet.
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#wallet").addClass("active");
</script>
```

In short, I'm confused why the `httpPost` controller action is receiving a valid `PrivateKey` object from the postback but the objects contained within the `PrivateKey` object are always null.

Thanks in advance!
--Oldtimer :)

Comment: You need to show your view - how have you generated the form control for properties of `WebUser`?

Comment: add `@Html.HiddenFor(x =>x.WebUser.property)` inside the BeginForm for all the properties you have within WebUser, so that the for has these values inside it and it can post them back for you to the controller. Now your form has no clue on this WebUser so you are getting null

Comment: You not generating any form controls for properties of `WebUser` so nothing relating to it is submitted back to the controller. Since your not editing anything related to `WebUser`, then just get it again in the POST method (just as you did in the GET method) - there is no point generating extra html by adding hidden inputs and then sending it back again unchanged (you will just open yourself to an over-posting attack by a  malicious user )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much everyone for the help. Adding the following code into my `PrivateKey` view solved the problem (as @Reddy suggested)

`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.WebUser.Padding)`

However, @Stephen Muecke and @gabriel make excellent points and I think I'm going to need to re-think the process flow of this application. Its currently a Webforms website and its written in a desktop application style, where objects are serialized and deserialized only when a new session is created/closed and these objects are passed around to all the pages whether those pages actually need all this data or not.

After digging into MVC and getting a better understanding of how Http actually works, I'm thinking this needs to change so only the data that is really needed is fetched and passed through the pipeline.

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your form is only posting back one of the properties. If you don't need it in your form then just capture it again during the post or change your view model appropriately.